# How to formulate linear programming optimization in PuLP?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am looking to formulate a (I think) complex LP problem in Python using PuLP.

- The optimization goal is to maximize profit margin (aggregate acquisition cost vs aggregate sale revenue plus some future appreciation (FV)) on a basket of products for purchase.
- The LP decision variables are pricing 'statistics' distinct for each product.
- The constraint is that the bid for a particular product cannot use a pricing statistic > some maximum value. 1.0 in this case. And the aggregate ratio of sum(FV) of won items to net revenue must be <= -2.0.

The price I'd bid is a function of a theoretical price plus a theoretical future value (FV) minus a theoretical cost. These 3 inputs are static - but the pricing statistic scales (or weights) the impact of the FV on the bid, which is what I'd like to solve for. Higher statistic -> higher bid. The trick is that once you change the statistic, you change the bid, and this changes the aggregates that PuLP is trying to optimize for. I figured this would be ok since the bid price is a closed form linear formula, but please see below for how I tried to tackle.

I also have the actual price the item sold for, so can compare the model's output price to the actual price to determine whether I would have bought in that case.

Concretely:

> Bid[item j] = Theo price + (***Statistic to be tuned[product i]*** * FV) - (Costs + Expenses)

There are 10 products to tune for, and j total items, non-uniformly distributed throughout a dataset.

If my output bid price based on the parameter being tuned in the LP > actual winning bid price, then consider the item purchased, and add it to the objective function.

Can someone please help me formulate this in PuLP? Maybe this is MIP? If so, I am unsure how to represent it formally.

What I have so far is the following:

```
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable, LpBinary
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

#create matrices and set variables 
MAX_STAT = 1.0
RATIO_CONSTRAINT = -2.0
PRODUCTS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ITEMS = df['ITEMS'].tolist() # IDs

#1xj dicts
ITEM_PRODUCT = {ITEMS[i]:df['PRODUCT'].iloc[i] for i in range(len(df))}
ACTUAL_PX = {ITEMS[i]:df['ACTUAL_PX'].iloc[i] for i in range(len(df))}
COST = {ITEMS[i]:df['COST'].iloc[i] for i in range(len(df))}
EXPENSE = {ITEMS[i]:df['EXPENSE'].iloc[i] for i in range(len(df))}

#ixj dicts
THEO_PX = {ITEMS[i]:[df['THEO_PX'].iloc[i] if PRODUCTS[ITEMS[i]] == x else 0for x in PRODUCTS] for i in range(len(df))}
QUANTITY = {ITEMS[i]:[df['QUANTITY'].iloc[i] if PRODUCTS[ITEMS[i]] == x else 0 for x in PRODUCTS] for i in range(len(df))}
FV = {ITEMS[i]:[df['FV'].iloc[i] if PRODUCTS[ITEMS[i]] == x else 0 for x in PRODUCTS] for i in range(len(df))}
use_vars = {j:[i if ITEM_PRODUCT[j] == i else 0 for i in PRODUCTS] for j in ITEMS}

#Define the model
model = LpProblem(name="maximize_margin", sense=LpMaximize)

#Define decision variables
strategy_statistic = LpVariable.dicts('StrategyStat', [(j,i) for j in ITEMS for i in PRODUCTS], 0, MAX_STAT)

#other variables dependent on the statistic
strategy_bid = {(j,i):strategy_statistic[(j,i)]*FV[j][i]+THEO_PX[j][i]-COST[j]-EXPENSE[j] for j in ITEMS for i in PRODUCTS}
win_loss = {(j,i):1 if strategy_bid[(j,i)] >= ACTUAL_PX[j] else 0 for j in ITEMS for i in PRODUCTS}

aggQuantity = lpSum(win_loss[(j,i)]*QUANTITY[j][i]*use_vars[j][i] for j in ITEMS for i in PRODUCTS)
aggTheo = lpSum(win_loss[(j,i)]*THEO_PX[j][i]*QUANTITY[j][i]*use_vars[j][i] for j in ITEMS for i in PRODUCTS)
aggFV = lpSum(win_loss[(j,i)]*FV[j][i]*QUANTITY[j][i]*use_vars[j][i] for j in ITEMS for i in PRODUCTS)
aggBidNotional = lpSum(win_loss[(j,i)]*strategy_bid[(j,i)]*QUANTITY[j][i]*use_vars[j][i] for j in ITEMS for i in PRODUCTS)


model += (aggTheo - aggBidNotional + aggFV)
model += (aggFV / (aggTheo - aggBidNotional)) <= RATIO_CONSTRAINT
```

Currently seeing an error on the last line saying that:

```
TypeError: Expressions cannot be divided by a non-constant expression
```

But I think there is more wrong with this formulation than that...

Comment: Note that PuLP is for linear models only. Your code is a  bit difficult to decipher (for me), but I think you introduce a few nonlinearities along the way. Usually, I write optimization models in a more structured way, and closer to the underlying mathematical model.

Comment: Yes, I guess rather than editing the code itself, maybe someone could help in formulating the mathematical model itself? Then given a well formed linear representation, I could translate that to PuLP with less trouble. Sorry about the code, would it help to add the head of the df?